# Docker multistage copy path list from files

Tags: docker, cmake, build, devops

I have a base image (mybase:1.0.0) which builds and installs a few CMake projects successfully.
I want to make a more specialised image (myapp:1.0.0) which is composed from mybase:1.0.0 and adds my application, which depends on the libraries and binaries installed in mybase:1.0.0.
Each CMake build creates install_manifest.txt which has a path to where each binary or library was installed>

Example manifest:

```
/usr/local/bin/myapp
/usr/local/lib/mylib.so
```

In my specialised image I would like to copy these paths to my new container, which should be based not on mybase:1.0.0 but another specialised (and compatible) image (in my case nvidia/cuda:10.2-base-ubuntu18.04).
To do so I would have my dockerfile something like:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-base-ubuntu18.04
COPY --from mybase:1.0.0 /usr/local/bin/myapp /usr/local/bin/myapp
COPY --from mybase:1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/mylib.so /usr/local/lib/mylib.so
```

My problem is that there are many (~200) files which need to be installed, and including them all in the dockerfile would be very ugly, and when the libraries update and the base image is built again, the dockerfile would need to be updated.

One solution would be to copy all the files from the build directory directly to /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib. But in order to reduce file size significantly, the build directories are removed (aside from the manifests) after the base image has installed them (which is a requirement).
A workaround to this would be to have a second 'pre-base' image which deletes the installed images after build (the build libraries have interdependencies which require them to be installed).

Is there a way to do a COPY --from where the contents of a manifest.txt specify the SRC paths?
Or any practices which do similar that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I asked for a feature request to do so, and I received a response on how to do it using the docker experimental API.

See: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1060#issuecomment-655566235